# Spyder extremely lags when exploring GeoDataFrame of a shapefile

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, lag, formatter

I do a simple tutorial on geopandas.

When I try to explore GeoDataFrame and scroll to "geometry" column, my IDE starts to lag extremely and my program almost crashes.
The only thing I have loaded in my IDE is one shapefile with polygons representing countries.
I run spyder as administrator.

What might be the issue?

[image]

"brak odpowiedzi" means "program is not responding" after I tried to scroll down a bit or do anything.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Perhaps the `geometry` column has too much data and that's the cause the large lag you're observing in Spyder. Is the shapely file you mentioned available on the web? That way we could test this problem and try to solve it in our side.

Comment: Hello, the file was too big and that was the problem I think. Another, smaller shape, loads normally. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I thought that was the problem too. But nice to know that Spyder is working fine with smaller files.